# Ruby on Rails: ratyrate gem table already exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-migrations

I'm using rails 5, and I've installed the gem and tried to run the migration, but I'm getting this error:

`Index name 'index_rates_on_rater_id' on table 'rates' already exists`

Does anyone know why this exists? This is a new site and started fresh just adding devise gem.

This is the migration file that wouldn't complete on execution `rails db:migrate`

```
class CreateRates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

  def self.up
      create_table :rates do |t|
        t.belongs_to :rater
        t.belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true
        t.float :stars, :null => false
        t.string :dimension
        t.timestamps
      end

      add_index :rates, :rater_id
      add_index :rates, [:rateable_id, :rateable_type]
    end

    def self.down
      drop_table :rates
    end

end
```

Comment: if you rollback and comment `add_index :rates, :rater_id` out and run the migration again does it work?

Comment: What does your db/schema.rb file look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gem creates a migration that does not work in later versions of rails. In Rails 5 when you use the `belongs_to` and `references` macros they create indices and foreign keys by default.

All you really need is this:

```
class CreateRates < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def self.change
    create_table :rates do |t|
      t.belongs_to :rater
      t.belongs_to :rateable, polymorphic: true
      t.float :stars, null: false
      t.string :dimension
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :rates, [:rateable_id, :rateable_type]
  end
end
```

You don't need `up` and `down` since Rails is smart enough to know how to rollback this migration.

Comment: I would really question if this particular gem is worth it based on the amount of activity on github.

Comment: This works, thank you! what would you think i could use in replacement of this gem, @max

Comment: dunno, I'm guessing the functionality is not all to hard to replicate on your own.

Comment: hmm, would it be okay if i still continue to use the gem and maybe work off of it? Or should I just take it completely off and start from scratch? I'm trying to get back to rails, and still a beginner. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @hellomello fork it, and contribute. change the migrations etc