# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::Colleges#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my first time working on Adding a back-end with Active Admin. The user side of my rails app http://localhost:3000/colleges is working fine but in my admin section http://localhost:3000/admin/colleges it's bringing up the following error. I have tried some solutions from stack overflow but no answer is relating to my error so far.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Admin::Colleges#index

Showing /home/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activeadmin-2.9.0/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: rates: SELECT "rates".* FROM "rates"
    #
    def prepare sql
      stmt = SQLite3::Statement.new( self, sql )
      return stmt unless block_given?

      begin
```

here is my files
colleges/index.html.erb

```
    <h1>Colleges</h1>

<% @colleges.in_groups_of(5) do |group| %>
  <div class="row">
    <% group.compact.each do |college| %>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= image_tag college.picture_url, width: '100%' if college.picture.present? %>
      
 <h4><%= link_to college.name, college %></h4>
        <%= college.description %>
        
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
```

Below is my colleges_controller.rb

```rb
class CollegesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_college, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /colleges or /colleges.json
  def index
    @colleges = College.all
  end

  # GET /colleges/1 or /colleges/1.json
  def show
    @comments = @college.comments.all
    @comment = @college.comments.build
  end

  # GET /colleges/new
  def new
    @college = College.new
  end

  # GET /colleges/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /colleges or /colleges.json
  def create
    @college = College.new(college_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @college.save
        format.html { redirect_to college_url(@college), notice: "College was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @college }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @college.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /colleges/1 or /colleges/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @college.update(college_params)
        format.html { redirect_to college_url(@college), notice: "College was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @college }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @college.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /colleges/1 or /colleges/1.json
  def destroy
    @college.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to colleges_url, notice: "College was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_college
      @college = College.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def college_params
      params.require(:college).permit(:name, :description, :picture, :rating, :apply)
    end
end
```

schema.rb

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2022_03_02_115834) do

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "colleges", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "region"
    t.string "name"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "picture"
    t.string "apply"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "seralno"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "user_name"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "college_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

stacktrace

```
sqlite3 (1.4.2) lib/sqlite3/database.rb:147:in `initialize'
sqlite3 (1.4.2) lib/sqlite3/database.rb:147:in `new'
sqlite3 (1.4.2) lib/sqlite3/database.rb:147:in `prepare'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:228:in `block (2 levels) in exec_query'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:48:in `block in permit_concurrent_loads'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:47:in `permit_concurrent_loads'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:213:in `block in exec_query'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:581:in `block (2 levels) in log'
/home/gatwiri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:580:in `block in log'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:571:in `log'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:212:in `exec_query'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:482:in `select_prepared'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:68:in `select_all'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:104:in `block in select_all'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:127:in `block in cache_sql'
/home/gatwiri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:113:in `cache_sql'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:104:in `select_all'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/querying.rb:41:in `find_by_sql'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/relation.rb:560:in `block in exec_queries'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/relation.rb:584:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/relation.rb:547:in `exec_queries'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/relation.rb:422:in `load'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/relation.rb:200:in `records'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:71:in `each'
formtastic (4.0.0) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/collections.rb:58:in `map'
formtastic (4.0.0) lib/formtastic/inputs/base/collections.rb:58:in `collection'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/inputs/filters/select_input.rb:43:in `collection'
formtastic (4.0.0) lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb:173:in `select_html'
formtastic (4.0.0) lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb:168:in `block in to_html'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:41:in `block in capture'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:205:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:41:in `capture'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/inputs/filters/base.rb:12:in `input_wrapping'
formtastic (4.0.0) lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb:166:in `to_html'
formtastic (4.0.0) lib/formtastic/helpers/input_helper.rb:239:in `input'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb:14:in `filter'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in active_admin_filters_form_for'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb:57:in `each'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb:57:in `block in active_admin_filters_form_for'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:41:in `block in capture'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:205:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:41:in `capture'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:452:in `form_for'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb:56:in `active_admin_filters_form_for'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element.rb:183:in `method_missing'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/filters/resource_extension.rb:168:in `block in filters_sidebar_section'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar_section.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar_section.rb:25:in `build_sidebar_content'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar_section.rb:13:in `build'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:94:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:50:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:27:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:40:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:15:in `sidebar_section'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar.rb:9:in `map'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/components/sidebar.rb:9:in `build'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:94:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:50:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:27:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:40:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:15:in `sidebar'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:84:in `block in build_page_content'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:32:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:94:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:50:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:27:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:40:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:15:in `div'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:82:in `build_page_content'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in build_page'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:32:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:94:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:50:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:27:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:40:in `insert_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:15:in `div'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:55:in `block in build_page'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:94:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:50:in `with_current_arbre_element'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:54:in `build_page'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/views/pages/base.rb:9:in `build'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:31:in `block in build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:94:in `with_current_arbre_element'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:27:in `build_tag'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/element/builder_methods.rb:40:in `insert_tag'
activeadmin (2.9.0) app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb:2:in `block in __home_gatwiri__rvm_gems_ruby_______gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_index_html_arb__856722158634028848_70301165774920'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:47:in `instance_eval'
arbre (1.5.0) lib/arbre/context.rb:47:in `initialize'
activeadmin (2.9.0) app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb:1:in `new'
activeadmin (2.9.0) app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb:1:in `__home_gatwiri__rvm_gems_ruby_______gems_activeadmin_______app_views_active_admin_resource_index_html_arb__856722158634028848_70301165774920'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:16:in `render'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:44:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:25:in `render'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:84:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `block in ms'
/home/gatwiri/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:31:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:240:in `default_render'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:172:in `to_html'
responders (3.0.1) lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:109:in `to_html'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:165:in `respond'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/responder.rb:158:in `call'
responders (3.0.1) lib/action_controller/respond_with.rb:213:in `respond_with'
inherited_resources (1.13.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:7:in `index'
activeadmin (2.9.0) lib/active_admin/resource_controller/streaming.rb:12:in `index'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.6.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.6.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.6.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.5.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.6.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.6.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
railties (5.2.6.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

model.rb

```rb
class College < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
    ratyrate_rateable 'culture', 'original_score', 'resources', 'academic_support'
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

Comment: Please share the full error message including the whole stack trace.

Comment: @spickermann I have added the stack trace

Comment: @Jad I have added the model

Comment: can I ask why you're using https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate ?

Comment: @Jad It's the link to ratyrate gem which am using in rating and reviews

Comment: Can you remove that from your model, and see if the error disappears? If it does, then reread the documentation for the gem, as it looks like you might have missed something in the setup

Comment: Thanks seem the error occurred due to pending migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had disabled `config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load` in `config/environment.rb`  file, hence pending migration error could not be shown.I ran `rake db:migrate:status` and some of my migrations were pending. I figured out the error was being caused by the ratyrate gem and I fixed using the following solution [Ruby on Rails: ratyrate gem table already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231420/ruby-on-rails-ratyrate-gem-table-already-exists).